# On 'perfectness' of coprime graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

A coprime graph, $G_n$ is a graph whose vertex set $V(G) = [n] = \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ and two vertices are adjacent iff they are coprime. I've been able to prove that the clique number of the graph, $\omega(G_n)$ is equal to its chromatic number, $\chi(G_n)$.

My question is why is $G_n$ not perfect for larger values of $n$? Does it have something to do with the prime numbers being more 'spaced-out' for larger $n$?

Answer (score 3):

If we can find an induced cycle of length 5 that would show that it is not perfect.

Take 5 primes $p_1,\ldots, p_5$. You can find 5 product pairs (like $p_1p_2$) such that they form an induced 5-cycle. I'll leave that to you in case this is an assignment or something.

Comment: Why would an induced cycle of length 5 show that it is not perfect? Sorry I'm new to this topic and a little confused.

Comment: Check out the wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph
Basically, a graph is perfect if chromatic number equals clique number for all induced subgraphs. A 5-cycle has clique number 2, but chromatic number 3.

Comment: You also might want to take a look at the Strong Perfect Graph Theorem. It characterizes perfect graphs in terms of forbidden induced subgraphs (which are the odd holes and odd antiholes in this case).